# Fit width and height to paper when printing a grid in UWP

Tags: uwp

I'm developing an app in UWP and I'm using a grid for some content. fore some reasons, I need to print the contents of the grid and I've written a code to do so.

The code is this:

```
    PrintManager printmgr = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    PrintDocument PrintDoc = null;
    PrintTask Task = null;
    private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager Sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
        Task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Sari-Tech", OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested);
        Task.Completed += PrintTask_Completed;
        deferral.Complete();
    }
    private void PrintTask_Completed(PrintTask Sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
    }
    private async void OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
    {
        var def = args.GetDeferral();
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
             // Set the print source 
             args.SetSource(PrintDoc?.DocumentSource);
            });
        def.Complete();
    }
    private void PrintDic_AddPages(Object Sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {
            PrintDoc.AddPage(sp_PrintArea);

        // completed to increase the printed page 
        PrintDoc.AddPagesComplete();
    }
    private void OnGetPreviewPage(Object Sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
    {
            PrintDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, sp_PrintArea);
    }
    private void PrintDic_Paginate(Object Sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintTaskOptions opt = Task.Options;
        PrintDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
    }
    async private void PrintGoBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PrintDoc != null)
        {
            PrintDoc.GetPreviewPage -= OnGetPreviewPage;
            PrintDoc.Paginate -= PrintDic_Paginate;
            PrintDoc.AddPages -= PrintDic_AddPages;
        }
        this.PrintDoc = new PrintDocument();

        PrintDoc.GetPreviewPage += OnGetPreviewPage;
        PrintDoc.Paginate += PrintDic_Paginate;
        PrintDoc.AddPages += PrintDic_AddPages;

        bool showPrint = await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
    }
```

Now I want these content to be completely fit to the paper. I don't know how to do this. I've tried to resize the grid to the size of an A4 paper but it didn't work because most of the content moved outside the screen size.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: salam saeed moshkele print ro hal kardi?man ham daghighan hamin moshkelaye ke shoma tu print darin daram mishe komakam konid?@fatemehebrahiminik id telegramam hast,f_3nik@yahoo.com ham emailam. montazeram, mamnon

Comment: @nik bebakhshid kheyli kheyli dir khoondam payametoono. ehtemalan alan dige moshkel hal shod. doroste?

Comment: are kheili ham dir shode kollan prozhe tamum shod va az sherkat umadam birun! ta jaye ke yadame moshekel kamel hal shod chon ta uno doros nakardam sherkat nazash bade etmame gharadad hatta hamkarimono tamum konam

Comment: @nik :)))))))))